# Improve SQLite anti-join performance

Tags: performance, sqlite, join

**Check out the update at the bottom of this question, the cause of the unexpected variance in query times noted below has been identified as the result of a sqliteman quirk**

I have the following two tables in a SQLite DB (The structure might seem pointless I know but bear with me)

```
+-----------------------+
| source                |
+-----------------------+
| item_id | time | data |
+-----------------------+

+----------------+
| target         |
+----------------+
| item_id | time |
+----------------+

--Both tables have a multi column index on item_id and time
```

The source table contains around 500,000 rows, there will never more than one matching record in the target table, in practise it is likely almost all source rows will have a matching target row.

I am attempting to a perform a fairly standard anti-join to find all records in source without corresponding rows in target, but am finding it difficult to create a query with an acceptable execution time.

The query I am using is:

```
SELECT
    source.item_id,
    source.time,
    source.data
FROM source
LEFT JOIN target USING (item_id, time)
WHERE target.item_id IS NULL;
```

Just the LEFT JOIN without the WHERE clause takes around 200ms to complete, with it this increases to 5000ms.

While I originally noticed the slow query from within my consuming application the timings above were obtained by executing the statements directly from within sqliteman.

Is there a particular reason why this seemingly simple clause so dramatically increases execution time and is there some way I can restructure this query to improve it?

I have also tried the following with the same result. (I imagine the underlying query plan is the same)

```
SELECT 
    source.item_id,
    source.time,
    source.data
FROM source
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM target
    WHERE target.item_id = source.item_id
    AND target.time = source.time
);
```

Thanks very much!

### Update

Terribly sorry, it turns out that these apparent results are actually due to a quirk with sqliteman.

It seems sqliteman arbitrarily applies a limit to the number of rows returned to 256, and will load more dynamically as you scroll through them. This will make a query over a large dataset appear much quicker then actually is, making it a poor choice for estimating query performance.

Nonetheless is their any obvious way to improve the performance of this query or am I simply hitting limits of what SQLite is capable of?

Comment: How exactly are you measuring the execution time? The IS NULL query should not be slower.

Comment: I added a note on that to the question. Those timings were obtained using the query tool within sqliteman.

Comment: Did that actually fetch all result rows? If not, measure instead `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (the actual query)`.

Comment: Sincere apologies, I should have verified the execution times utilising other query tools, as it turns out the faster query is a result of a sqliteman quirk. 
Thank you!

Comment: The query plan does not actually change, but when there are fewer results, you need to search through more table rows to get the first 256 results.

Comment: Fair call, I've updated the update to reflect that. Given that this query now behaves consistently slow, I'm guessing it is simply a matter of having hit limits of what SQlite is capable of, and I will have to look for other options.

Comment: Show the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html). (If it is already using the covering index, nothing can be done.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [query plan](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) of your query (either one):

```
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE source
0|1|1|SEARCH TABLE target USING COVERING INDEX ti (item_id=? AND time=?)
```

This is pretty much as efficient as possible:

1. Every row in `source` must be checked, by
2. searching for a matching row in `target`.

It might be possible to make one little improvement.
The `source` rows are probably not ordered, so the `target` search will do a lookup at a random position in the index.
If we can force the `source` scan to be in index order, the `target` lookups will be in order too, which makes it more likely for these index pages to already be in the cache.

SQLite will use the `source` index if we do not use any columns not in the index, i.e., if we drop the `data` column:

```
> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
  SELECT source.item_id, source.time
  FROM source
  LEFT JOIN target USING (item_id, time)
  WHERE target.item_id IS NULL;
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE source USING COVERING INDEX si
0|1|1|SEARCH TABLE target USING COVERING INDEX ti (item_id=? AND time=?)
```

This might not help much.
But if it helps, and if you want the other columns in `source`, you can do this by doing the join first, and then looking up the `source` rows by their `rowid` (the extra lookup should not hurt if you have very few results):

```
SELECT *
FROM source
WHERE rowid IN (SELECT source.rowid
                FROM source
                LEFT JOIN target USING (item_id, time)
                WHERE target.item_id IS NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I can confirm that while the query you described is not any faster initially, subsequent calls are significantly so, which is behaviour not observed with my original query.